# PHP: How to get multiple checkbox values from database for same ID?

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php & need little help here.
I've following code to INSERT multiple checkbox values into a table for same ID:

on my form I have:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="Mech">Mech
<input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="Ele">Ele
<input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="Civ">Civ
<input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="Air">Air
<input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="BSL">BSL
```

I've checked "Mech", "Ele" and "BSL"

and PHP to insert:

```
$subcat = $_POST['subcat'];
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($subcat);$i++){
    $sql1="INSERT INTO mst_scatadd (party_code,scid)
    VALUES ('$pcode',$subcat[$i])";
    mysql_query($sql1,$con);
    }
```

db looks something like...

```
sctid  | party_code  |   scid
---------------------------------
  1    |   01S001    |    Mech
  2    |   01S001    |    Ele
  3    |   01S001    |    BSL
  4    |   01K207    |    Main
```

Now, how can I retrieve these values from db to my form for the same ID and make them as checked if I want to edit the checkboxes?

Little help would be appreciated!!

Thanks in adv.

### EDIT 1:

Hello again guys!

I've done with inserting and retrieving checkbox values using implode and explode and its working fine.
Thanks to @Antoniossss for good suggession to keep checkboxes values as numbers(make sure the column in db should be VARCHAR)
Thanks to @Barmar to explain use of explode & thanks to @MarkTWebsite to share idea of if-else

Code for inserting multiple checkbox values:

```
foreach ($_POST['subcat'] as $_subcat)
    {
        $checksub[] = $_subcat;
    }   $finalsub = implode(',', $checksub);

$sql="INSERT INTO vendor_mst(party_code, subcat) VALUES ('$pcode','$finalsub')";
```

My final code to retrieve checkbox values from db...

```
sql="SELECT * FROM vendor_mst WHERE party_code like '".$searchname."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql,$con);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH)){
$checksub  = explode(',',$row['subcat']);
}
if(in_array("1",$checksub))echo '<input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="1" checked >Mech'; else echo '<input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="1">Mech';
if(in_array("2",$checksub))echo '<input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="2" checked >Ele';  else echo '<input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="2">Ele';
if(in_array("3",$checksub))echo '<input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="3" checked >Civ';  else echo '<input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="3">Civ';
if(in_array("4",$checksub))echo '<input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="4" checked >Air';  else echo '<input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="4">Air';
if(in_array("5",$checksub))echo '<input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="5" checked >BSL';  else echo '<input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="5">BSL';
```

Thanks to stackoverflow!

Comment: you insert code has a bug `VALUES ('$pcode',$saincat[$i])";` should be  `VALUES ('$pcode',$subcat[$i])";`

Comment: Offtopic: Mysql is deprecated, try using PDO or MysqlI

Comment: @ DevZer0 - Thanks for reply but it's a typo. My question is how to retrieve these values?

Comment: `SELECT scid FROM  mst_scatadd where party_code = '01S001'`

Comment: Parameterize queries to avoid SQL Injection

Answer (score 1):

I would rather go in direction of threating checkboxes as binary flags and store their binary OR operation into DB as integer. It is really easy to implement, and will simplify record relations in your database. To do that you need to change values of checkboxes into 2^n values. For example

```
<input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="1">Mech
<input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="2">Ele
<input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="4">Civ
<input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="8">Air
<input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="16">BSL
```

selecting `Mech` and `Civ` should be storen in DB as 5  (binary 00101), `Air`+`BSL` would be 24 (11000b) and so on. To revert this process you would just simply test every bit of stored value and check/uncheck corresponding boxes in loop. I hope that you will get my point.

**EDIT**: example code as requested.
Be aware that **I AM NOT** a PHP programmer so there could (and definetly will be) syntax errors but I will do my best
To get user input you have to simply add values of checked boxes

```
$selected=0;
foreach($POST['subcat'] as $checkedBox){
    $selected=$selected+$checkedBox
    }
```

So now variable `$selected` will have encoded status of all checkboxes
To check which boxes (I never have troubles with that word) should be check or not you have to test every bit of stored value in DB. I dont know how are you generating your view, so i will provide only a template, you have to figure it out how to apply it to your project

```
$valueFromDb= ///  some value fetched from DB
$maxValue= //// the highest value of your checkboxes, in my eg. 16
for($testValue=1;$testValue<=$limit;$testValue=$testValue << 1){
    $result=($valueFromDb & $testValue) > 0;
    // do something with checked result for current checkbox
}
```

variable `result` above will have `checked` status (boolean value) of coresponding checkboxes. Each loop iteration coresponds to different checkbox in order from Mech to BSL one by one.
Alternatively you can print checkboxes directly and set them as checked with `if` inscruction 
    $valueFromDb= // fetched value

```
<input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="1" <?php if($valueFromDb & 1 >0) echo('checked') ?php>Mech
<input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="2" <?php if($valueFromDb & 2 >0) echo('checked') ?php>>Ele
<input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="4" <?php if($valueFromDb & 4 >0) echo('checked') ?php>>Civ
 .... and so on and on and on
```

I have just noticed that combining those 2 methods would result in generating checboxes dynamicly in loop so the code will be much more readable. All you would need is to provide map of checbox value labels:)
I hope that eg. above will definetlly clearify how to apply such solution.

Comment: I think this is good way to handle db. But can you give an example to retrieve these int values?

Comment: It would be helpful if you give some coding for above example to check corresponding boxes(considering that values are integer)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
 $checksub = array('1','2','3');

?>

<form action="<?php echo site_url('index/do_upload') ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Select file : <input type="file" name="userfile"></label>
    <input type="submit" name="action">
    <input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="1" <?php if (in_array(1,$checksub)){ echo "checked"; }?>/> 

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the PHP if statement;
I don't really understand your db structure, else I would provide code however, if you use PHP if, for each checkbox, check in the database to see if it's selected then;
if it is selected

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="Mech" selected>Mech';
```

else;

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="Mech">Mech';
```

Do you understand what I mean?

Source; HTML/CSS/PHP Developer for 3 years.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. Yes I am using PHP. Isn't it possible to store these values in an array? If yes, can you let me know the coding? Regarding db it's a simple table which stores different sub-categories (scid) for same party code (plz don't be confuse for scid. My PK is "sctid")

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the subcats with:

```
SELECT party_code, GROUP_CONCAT(scid) scids
FROM mst_scadd
GROUP BY party_code
```

Then when you're fetching the rows from the database, you can do:

```
$scids = array_flip(explode(',', $row['scids']));
```

That will create an associative array whose keys are the subcategories. Then your code for displaying the checkboxes can be something like:

```
foreach ($all_subcats as $sc) {
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="subcat[]" value="' . $sc . '" ' .
        (isset($scids[$sc]) ? 'checked' : '') . '>' . $sc;
}
```